# Вывод данных в модальное окно из базы

Tags: javascript, c#, mysql, asp.net

Есть сайт с таблицей контактов.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все отлично, я забираю данные из базы все работает.

Теперь проблема с кнопкой "Узнать все". Это кнопка вызова модального окна.

```
<td>                                        
<asp:Button ID="ShowContact" runat="server" Text="Узнать всё" data-toggle="modal" CssClass="btn btn-success btn-xs" CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("id") %>' data-target="#myModal" OnCommand="ShowContact_Click"/>
</td>
```

Тут я передаю id записи `CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("id") %>'`, по которой вызвали модальное окно.

как я понимаю, мне нужно по событию клик `OnCommand="ShowContact_Click"` 
отправить запрос в базу и получить данные по контакту.Как мне это сделать?

```
protected void ShowContact_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            int rowInd = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            conn = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLString"].ConnectionString);
            comm = new MySqlCommand("Команда", conn);

        }
    }
```

База типа

```
persons

+----+-----------+-----+
| id | firstname | age |
+----+-----------+-----+
|  1 | Катя      |  12 |
|  2 | Лена      |  18 |
+----+-----------+-----+
email

    +----+-----------+-----------+
    | id | email     | person_id |
    +----+-----------+-----------+
    |  1 | wer@sdf.ru|  1        |
    |  2 |           |  2        |
    +----+-----------+-----------+
telephone

    +----+-----------+-----------+
    | id | phone     | person_id |
    +----+-----------+-----------+
    |  1 | 3423434324|  1        |
    |  2 |           |  2        |
    +----+-----------+-----------+
```

Как мне в заголовок модального окна передать ФИО человека?

Код модального окна:

```
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
       <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upModal" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" UpdateMode="Conditional">
         <ContentTemplate>
            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">
                        </h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
              </ContentTemplate>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду под модальным окном, раз речь идет, как я понимаю об ASP.Net (судя по тегу). Каким образом оно реализовано: как отдельное окно, как блок или как?

Comment: Это бутстраповское окно.     <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">

Comment: Так в чем все-таки вопрос? Не получается получить данные из базы (судя по заголовку), или нужно полученные из базы данные передать в окно bootstrap (т.е. передать данные из back-end во front-end)? Отобразить само окно по кнопке у Вас получилось?

Comment: @ella-svetlaya Да отобразить модальное окно не проблема. Но как мне исходя из id выбранного таблице, отобразить в модальном в заголовке ФИО. То есть выбрали Марину и нажали кнопку "Узнать все". Как мне в открывшемся модальном окне отобразить ФИО, дальше я сам разберусь. Спасибо!

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, в чем проблема. Просто присвойте нужный текст в label. Например, `labelModalTitle = strUserFIO;` Покажите код модального окна.

Comment: К сожалению так не работает

Comment: Покажите код модального окна.

Comment: Ну так вставьте в H4 label и присваивайте полученное из базы значение.

Comment: Если проблема именно с получением данных, то см. здесь - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7061329/mysqlcommand-executereader-getstring-does-not-work

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29592/discussion-between-shatoidil-and-ella-svetlaya).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому-то пригодиться!

```
protected void ShowContact_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int rowInd = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    conn = new MySqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySQLString"].ConnectionString);

    comm = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM persons WHERE id = @id", conn);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", rowInd);
    conn.Open();
    List<string> fio = new List<string>();
    MySqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Pop", "openModal();", true);
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        this.FIO.Text = string.Format("{0} {1} {2}", reader.GetString("lastname"), reader.GetString("firstname"), reader.GetString("middlename"));
    }
    reader.Close();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Добавьте в запросе `LIMIT 1`, т.к. надо вернуть лишь одну запись.